# Change xml attribute c#

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

Need to change attribute with `name = "SqlServer"`

Config file just like xml, not from my project

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServer"
             connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.1; Initial Catalog=s; Application Name=s; MultipleActiveResultSets = true; Pooling=True; User ID=1111;Password=1111;" />       

    <add name="SqlServer_WinAuthentication"
             connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=MeterShop; Integrated Security=True; Application Name=MeterShop; MultipleActiveResultSets = true; Pooling=True;" />

    <add name="SqlServer_SqlAuthentication"
             connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=MeterShop; User ID=1; Password=1; Application Name=1; MultipleActiveResultSets = true; Pooling=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? or please show what you have done...

Comment: all what i have done - just  load xml, and get all nodes of connectionstrings

Comment: So you want to add a new node or update name of any existing node under ConnectionStrings node

Comment: update the old one with name "SqlServer" for example

Comment: Can you post your code? How you load the xml and select the node?

Comment: here what i have

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Web.config");
            var connectionStrings = doc.SelectSingleNode("//connectionStrings").ChildNodes;

Comment: in result i get three xmlchildnodes, but i have no idea how to get value from them

Comment: there is only one way what i found - 
var connectionString = doc.SelectSingleNode("//connectionStrings").ChildNodes[0];
ConnectionStringTb.Text = connectionString.Attributes[1].Value;

but i hope, there is some pocibilities to take it just by name of child ("SqlServer") and get/set it's attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve this, I prefer `Linq` to Xml

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
var target = doc.Descendants("connectionStrings")           
                .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Element("add").Attribute("name").Value == "SqlServer");
```

Once you get the target element, you can update the value.

```
target.Element("add").Attribute("name").Value = "any thing you want";
doc.Save("filename"); // Save the file after your changes.
```

Working [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vijRsS)

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication70
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
            "<connectionStrings>" +
                "<add name=\"SqlServer\"" +
                         " connectionString=\"Data Source=192.168.1.1; Initial Catalog=s; Application Name=s; MultipleActiveResultSets = true; Pooling=True; User ID=1111;Password=1111;\" />" +
                "<add name=\"SqlServer_WinAuthentication\"" +
                         " connectionString=\"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=MeterShop; Integrated Security=True; Application Name=MeterShop; MultipleActiveResultSets = true; Pooling=True;\" />" +
                "<add name=\"SqlServer_SqlAuthentication\"" +
                         " connectionString=\"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=MeterShop; User ID=1; Password=1; Application Name=1; MultipleActiveResultSets = true; Pooling=True;\" />" +
            "</connectionStrings>";

            XElement connectionStrings = XElement.Parse(xml);

            List<XAttribute> names = connectionStrings.Descendants("add").Select(x => x.Attribute("name")).ToList();
            foreach (XAttribute name in names)
            {
                name.Value = "123";
            }
        }

    }
}
```